# Angularjs and Java - Different hours between timezones

Tags: java, angularjs, timezone

My web application uses in front end bootstrap 3.3.7, ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.1 and angular 1.5.8. In back end Java 8, tomcat 8 and 
provide JSON rest services. The TimeZone in server is America/Sao_Paulo, in frond end is America/Bahia.

The Html for input date uses uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"
For input time uses

```
<div uib-timepicker ng-model="model.jogo.data" 
    hour-step="1" 
    minute-step="1" 
    show-meridian="false">
</div>
```

No date parse occurs on the server. The piece of the angular controller code that gets json from server is:

```
    var find = function (jogoId) {
        Jogo.getById({id: jogoId}).$promise.then(function (result) {
            $scope.model.jogo = result;
            console.log($scope.model.jogo.data);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

In MysSql database the date is saved as "2018-01-16 17:00:00". After query, the server returns a json with the timestamp date 1516129200000
The date is displayed on the screen as 16/01/2018 16:00 (one hour before). Then the date is changed to 16/01/2018 17:00 on browser and submit.

The piece of the angular controller code that post json is:

```
    $scope.salvar = function() {
        console.log($scope.model.jogo.data);
        $scope.model.jogo.$save().then(function (resilt) {
            $location.path('/jogo/list');
        });
    };
```

Before post the console.log puts Tue Jan 16 2018 17:00:00 GMT-0300. Then the server saves on database. Querying the database, 
the date is now stored as 2018-01-16 20:00:00.

Can someone help me solve this time difference problem ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.  You've described multiple layers, but only showed code for part of one of them.  Without a complete example for us to follow, it's going to be quite difficult to help.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then come back and edit your question according to the guidance described there.

Comment: Epoch millis of 1516129200000 equal 2018-01-16 19:00:00 UTC or 2018-01-16 17:00:00 Sao Paolo (UTC-02:00 because of summer time), in turn equal to 16:00 in Bahia (UTC-03:00).

Comment: Just a wild guess, could it be that the browser submit Sao Paolo time and the server thinks it gets Bahia time??

Comment: A tip, rather than epoch milliseconds transfer ISO 8601 strings in UTC between browser and server. Like `2018-01-16T19:00:00Z`. They are much easier to read in a debugging situation.